# Routing error with has_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-scope

I am getting the error below with has_scope. This seems like a really obvious and basic error but I just can't work it out. I'd really appreciate any help that can be offered.

I have got ActiveAdmin elsewhere on the site and I believe that uses it so we can assume the gem is operating correctly.

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /products
undefined method `has_scope' for ProductsController:Class
```

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category

    # Scopes
    default_scope { order('end_date DESC') } 
    scope :upward_trending, -> { where( "status > ?", 100).order('end_date DESC') }
end
```

Controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    has_scope :upward_trending

    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:name, :status)
    end

    def index
        @q = Product.search(params[:q])
        @products = apply_scopes(@q.result.page(params[:page]).per(5)).all
    end


    def show
    end

end
```

Routes:

```
resources :products, only: [:index]
```

Comment: Do you have `has_scope` gem listed on your `Gemfile'?

Comment: Hey @BroiSatse thanks for your comment, yes I do - `has_scope (0.6.0.rc)  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of the gem `has_scope`[https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope], it looks like you need to pass in `:type` as `:boolean` to `has_scope` method in the controller. This is applicable to the scopes that do not accept a parameter.

```
has_scope :upward_trending, :type => :boolean
```

Comment: Great pick up, thank you for that. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error :( Any other ideas

Comment: From the error, it does look like the gem is not being loaded as @BroiSatse suggested. Try stopping and restarting the server if you haven't already.